# unable to understand ON in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT y.id
FROM Weather x
LEFT JOIN Weather y ON x.Id +1 = y.Id
WHERE x.Temperature < y.Temperature
```

this condition -> `ON x.Id +1 = y.Id` im confused how it works

Comment: ```ON``` is basic join-syntax: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Think of it as an expression. Eg: (x.Id+1) = y.Id. Says, match up records where on adding 1 to x.Id gives me the value as that of y.Id

Comment: Adding x.id to select would be a simple way to clarify..

Comment: `x.Id + 1 = y.Id` is a just a predicate. It means that rows from the table `Weather y` will be joined to the driving table **only** if the predicate evaluates to true. That's it.